# Xcode with SDK 4.2 always starting iPad Simulator

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-simulator, ios-4.2

Why does Xcode, after updating to SDK 4.2, always run my application in iPad Simulator instead of iPhone???
If I select iPhone Simulator as active executable it doesn't store my preference and runs the iPad simulator after any new Build & Run.

Comment: Are you sure it is the iPad simulator and not the retina simulator? Just wondering.

Comment: I haven't tried the 4.2, but a few months ago I ran into something where if I chose 3.2.2 as the target OS it always launched the iPad, and if I did 4.0 for the OS it always did the iPhone simulator

Comment: lol. i have exactly the opposite problem. iphone sim is always started.

Comment: Yes Kevin, it's the iPad Simulator wwith the possibility to scale 2x my app.
Chris, iOS deployment target is 4.0.

Comment: similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322279/ios-simulator-how-can-i-make-default-simulator-as-iphone/5284694#5284694

Comment: This only just recently started happening to me. All I can think of is that I have recently installed Xcode 3.2.6 with iOS SDK 4.3. Everything was going okay until I ran a build on my phone. Before that it was running on the iPhone simulator just fine for the last couple of days.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same Problem. But suddenly after an Update it disappeared. Do you have the newest Version of all Software( or tried turning it off and on again)?

If that doesn't works, I would suggest a reinstall. Solved many of my Problems...

Answer (score 2):

On XCode 3.2.6, you can go to "Project" menu -> "Set Active Executable" and select iPhone Simulator.

Answer (score 1):

Try to Build -> 'Clean All Targets'. Go into Release configuration, compile and then back to Debug. Now you can choose Iphone Simulator. For me it works.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Active Executable setting, as well as the Simulator's setting for "Device."

Comment: I manually set...
Active SDK: iOS Simulator 4.2
Active Executable: iPhone Simulator 4.2

Everything runs fine, but if I close Xcode and restart it, automatically switchs back to iPad Simulator 4.2.

Comment: Same with me. After restarting Xcode it switches back to iPad Simulator 4.3.

Comment: Ouch, Xcode 4 is not giving me any problem anymore... but I guess you're on Xcode 4, so I should be afraid of it.

Answer (score 0):

Check your .xcodeproj info. Navigate yourself in there and locate Simulator's  Settings and choose 'iPhone' or 'iPad'

Hope this helps

Comment: Sorry, but I can't find the Simulator's setting in the project info pane.

Comment: how about the target <project name>.app? I only seen the xcode 4.2 once and never gotten to play with it since then.

Answer (score 0):

Removing all iPad devices from the device list in the organizer (Window Menu > Organizer) fixed it for me. But i know that's not a perfect solution. I hope Apple will fix this soon.

Answer (score 0):

do yo have two xcode (or iphone sdk) installation on your machine? if yes then completely uninstall the xcode using this command -

```
sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools –mode=all
```

from all the locations (replace Developer with installed directory name)

and install the xcode 3.2.6 in developer directory

Answer (score 0):

You can go to `Product -> Destination -> iPhone 6.1 Simulator`.

It took me a while to figure out the reason, because even though you select the Device `iPhone` in `Targets`, it still opens the iPad emulator if you don't change the destination of your product.