# iOS simulator - How can I make default simulator as iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios-simulator

I downloaded latest XCode with iOS 4.2 version.
When I'm testing any app in simulator, its running in ipad simulator by default.
How can I make my simulator default to iPhone.

Comment: Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4309165/xcode-with-sdk-4-2-always-starting-ipad-simulator

Comment: there is a radar for it here: http://openradar.appspot.com/8100399

Comment: Still happening in 3.6.2. Most irritating

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Solution#1

You can remove the iPad from the organizer. I haven't tried it, since I use both iPhone and iPad.

---

### Solution#2

Create a keyboard shortcut to switch to to the iPhone simulator

**top menu** > **Project** > **Set Active Executable** > **Targetname - iPhone Simulator**

See these screenshots

[image: Menu that we want to target with a keyboard shortcut]
[image: How to setup the keyboard shortcut]

Comment: I can confirm as of Xcode 7.2.1 that solution #2 still works, but the simulator menu location has changed to Product > Destination

Answer (score 10):

I hope this is what you're looking for, but in the top left of XCode, you should see a drop down bar that reads something like "Simulator - 4.2 | Debug | projName". If you click on that, you should see a section titled "Active Executable". There should be a small number of options to select the device and OS for the simulator. For instance, mine is currently selected to "projName - iPhone Simulator 4.2"

Hope that helps.

Comment: That works until you clean the project or add files to it - then Xcode switches it back to iPad simulator for no good reason...very frustrating.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Xcode switches back to the iPad simulator the same way as you describe. So frustating :-(

Answer (score 2):

1. Right click your project's name inside Xcode, select "Get Info".
2. Under "Deployment" section, set "Targeted Device Family" to iPhone.

Comment: Make sure you're configuring your "Active" configuration.

Comment: In "All Configurations", its set to iPhone.

Answer (score 2):

Open Xcode -> Product Menu -> Destination -> Select desired destination.  sticks when I restart.

Comment: Unfortunately only for that one project but it's something :)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution to this is simply to change your active executable. 
Go to project -> set active executable -> iPhone whatever version you want

Answer (score -1):

I finally solved this problem myself.

First, install new version of xCode, which is xCode 4.

Then set project scheme to iphone simulator and run app in xCode several times.

And re-install xCode 3 and the problem will be gone away!